# Color Code Due Date in Display Template to Red

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template

I have a great display template that is working almost as expected.  I now have a request to have the Due Date show RED once it is past due. I am still learning how to change things in the display template but for the most part it is working well.

How can I add the var to tell it if it is past due to change it to red.  I am using regular date column in the list, and have a refinabledate managed property for the display template.  I am only wanting the date and have ensured that the field is set to that.

I would appreciate any help.
Dorinda

PS if anyone can help get the date display to work I would love that as well I would like it to be just mm/dd/yyyy but the time is still showing up and I cannot figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In this sample I check the revision date against current date . In the HTML section you can switch on the boolean and either display the date in red or black

[image: code sample from Item Display template]

Comment: I dont have a revision date to check against I just want it to check against todays date and if it is past that date due show as red.  I am not sure how to implement this?

Comment: Just substitute revision date with your due date.

Comment: This is the same answer you gave me before and I couldnt get it to work.  I am even starting from scratch and having issues.

Comment: The refinabledate field contains the due date, right? So var duedate = $getItemValue(ctx, refinabledate XX) will allow you to compre duedate with today

Comment: This is what I am showing in the display template and now it is not working at all  var duedate = $getItemValue(ctx, "Refinabledate02") ;
        var ContentExpired = false; 
        if(!$isEmptyString(revisiondate.inputValue))
        {
            var thisdate = new Date();
            var parseRevDate = new Date(revisiondate);
            revisiondate = parseRevDate.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
            if(parseRevDate < thisdate)
            {
                ContentExpired = true;
            }
        }

Comment: Replace revisiondate with duedate and it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91431/discussion-between-dorinda-and-kasper-bo-larsen).